# apply multiple filters react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 buttons which when clicked should filter by `novelty` or `offer` , I am able to make it so that when novelty is clicked it will filter by this but I am unable to make it so that if both are click it will filter by both `novelty` and `offer`

How can I make it so that when both novelty and offer are clicked it will filter by both of these?

https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KpVGNEN7ZuKAFODxuER

```
import React from 'react'

export default class extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      products: [
        { id: 1, novelty: true, offer: false, name: 'test1' },
        { id: 2, novelty: true, offer: true, name: 'test2' },
        { id: 3, novelty: false, offer: true, name: 'test3' } 
        ],
      display: 'all',
      filters: [
        {novelty:'true'},
        {offer: 'true'}
      ]
    }
  }

  setCategory (category) {
    this.setState({
      display: category 
    });
  }

 render() {
   return(
   <div>
      <button onClick={()=>this.setCategory(true)}>Akce</button>
      <button onClick={()=>this.setCategory(true)}>Offer</button>
           {
      this.state.products.filter( product => 
       products.offer === this.state.display ||
        this.state.display==='all')
        .map(product =>
         <div>{product.name}</div>
           )
            }
   </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: The link you provided doesn't work...

Comment: works for me, but have updated the link

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is the final version I've come up with:

```
import React from 'react'

export default class extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      products: [
        { id: 1, novelty: true, offer: false, name: 'test1' },
        { id: 2, novelty: true, offer: true, name: 'test2' },
        { id: 3, novelty: false, offer: true, name: 'test3' } 
        ],
      filters: {
        novelty: true,
        offer: true
      }
    }
  }

  setCategory (category) {
    this.setState((state) => ({
      filters: Object.assign({}, state.filters, { [category]: !state.filters[category] })
    }));
  }

 render() {
   console.log(this.state.filters)
   return(
   <div>
      <button onClick={()=>this.setCategory('novelty')}>Akce</button>
      <button onClick={()=>this.setCategory('offer')}>Offer</button>
           { this.state.products
                       .filter(product => product.novelty === this.state.filters.novelty || product.offer === this.state.filters.offer)
                       .map(product =>
             <div key={product.id}>{product.name}</div>
           )}
   </div>
    )
  }
}
```

https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KpVHqfkjeraq6pGvHij

A few things:

- Using a boolean instead of a string in your case is more adapted. (`true` instead of `'true'`).
- `display: 'all'` isn't required for your use case. You can compute this value from your filters if you need to.
- `setCategory` receive which `category` you want to set as a param.
- I would rename `setCategory` to `setFilter`

Also, I'm using the asycnhronous version of `setState`. This allows you to hand in a function.

```
this.setState((state) => ({
      filters: Object.assign({}, state.filters, { [category]: !state.filters[category] })
}));
```

Here I'm using `Object.assign` to create a new Object. I populate him with  `state.filters` and finally I update the filter you want to.
`category` will either be `novelty` or `offer` and thanks to that I'm using the shorthand version of `[category]`.

To conclude, I also update your `filter` function to check the `product.novelty` against the `filter.novelty` or the `product.offer` with the `filter.offer`

Comment: this is great! exactly what I was after and thank you for taking the time to explain everything so clearly!

Comment: Beat me to it. I got hung up on the object assign, but besides that our code was identical.

Comment: Is it possible to display all items if `novelty` and `offer` are both false, it will display the items if one of the fields === true but won't show otherwise

Comment: @Chad yep me too. At first I wrote `filters: { ...state.filters, { [category]: !state.filters[category] } }` but then saw it was not supporting this ES6 syntax. So Object.assign ;)

Comment: @tomharrison hmm maybe something like this:
`.filter(product => (!this.state.filters.novelty || ( this.state.filters.novelty && product.novelty)) && (!this.state.filters.offer || (this.state.filters.offer && product.offer)))` (not tested though.. but what you want is, if the filter is true, then check if the product is true too. If the filter is false, then let the product pass anyway). Can be improved I'm pretty sure, just play around ;)

Comment: this codepen should help you as well: https://codepen.io/Dmitriy_Dubravin/pen/YWZjWQ?editors=0010